# Ion-select placeholder not updating after navigating away and back again

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have this code for a select in inoic

```
<ion-select  cancelText="Dismiss" (ionChange)="onPersonChange($event)" [placeholder]="placeholder">
```

The "placeholder" variable is the current user's name. The drop holds a list of all users.

On the page, if I select Person1 from the list (who is not the current user) everything works fine. all the data on the page is updated correctly.

However, if I navigate to a different page and then come back to this page, the placeholder will still show Person1's name.

in ionWiewWillEnter, I have this

```
this.placeholder = this.allPersons.filter((p) => p.isCurrentUser)[0].personName;
```

If I do a `console.log(this.placeholder)`,  the correct name is logged. but again, the dropdown on the screen still shows Person1 as the placeholder.

I want the placeholder to always show the current user when navigating to the page.  Any ideas what I can do about this?

(using ionic 7.1.1  and angular 16.1.7)  thank you in advance